# Send "| grep pattern" in Paramiko in a non-unix enviroment

Tags: ssh, grep, paramiko

Im trying to send a command to a non-unix enviroment like this `show configuration | grep interfaces` with Paramiko (Python3.5), but I get a `show configuration` output. It seems paramiko does not send the `| grep interfaces`. Somebody knows how to solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced Paramiko with Netmiko and the issue is solved.